# Error with fonts android studio 3: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

```
Error:(18) No resource found that matches the given name (at '^index_0' with value '@font/amita_bold').
Error:(18) No resource found that matches the given name (at '^index_0' with value '@font/amita_bold').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 35.612 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: pls help me why i received this error, and what to do, thank you very much...

Comment: This is very direct error, there is no such file under res/font directory

Answer (score 0):

Error itself saying that you didn't added any font style file. You need to download the Amita-Bold.ttf file from [this](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amita?selection.family=Amita) link. Download the file and unzip the folder. You will get 2 files. Add required file under your res/font directory.